# How do I get hibernate to eagerly fetch EmbeddedId?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, lazy-initialization

I occasionally get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.dd.translation.domain.postgres.Offer#OfferKey(offerId=03Y, difId=b3e79b1925ce4e41905a2ce214943d1f)] - no Session
```

Embeddable:

```java
@Builder
@Embeddable
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OfferKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "offer_id", columnDefinition = "CHARACTER VARYING(64) NOT NULL")
    private String offerId;

    @Column(name = "dif_id", columnDefinition = "CHARACTER VARYING(64) NOT NULL")
    private String difId;

}
```

Embedded object:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "offers")
public class Offer {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OfferKey offerId;
    private LocalDateTime validDate;
}
```

There is no other lazy loading in this project and I wouldn't assume I would need `@Transactional` for it. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to manually set it to eager or if anyone has run into this issue. I personally do not use this pattern but it is in existing code and I am trying to figure out if I need to rip it out or if there is an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the `Offer` object you are trying to access is not initialized, not the embedded id.

I guess you have something like this in one of your models:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
Offer offer;
```

Wherever you load the entity containing that association, you will have to make sure the offer is properly initialized, as apparently the calling code expects it can access offer details.

You can change the `FetchType` to EAGER, but I wouldn't recommend that. The better solution would be to apply a `@EntityGraph` on the repository method that instructs it to load the association.